# The difference between implicit and explicit delegate creation (with and without generics)

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-2.0, delegates

*See the four lines in the Go() method below:*

```
delegate void Action<T>(T arg);
delegate void Action();

void DoSomething<T>(Action<T> action)
{
    //...
}

void DoSomething(Action action)
{
    //...
}

void MyAction<T>(T arg)
{
    //...
}

void MyAction()
{
    //...
}

void Go<T>()
{
    DoSomething<T>(MyAction<T>); // throws compiler error - why?
    DoSomething(new Action<T>(MyAction<T>)); // no problems here
    DoSomething(MyAction); // what's the difference between this...
    DoSomething(new Action(MyAction)); // ... and this?
}
```

Note that the compiler error generated by the first call is:
*The type arguments for method 'Action(T)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.*

Comment: I can't understand how this would compile (in isolation):

    void DoSomething(Action<T> action)
    {
        //...
    }
Since T is not declared... Is the whole thing inside a generic class?

Comment: Yeah I'm modifying my example now. Should have read Go<T>(){...

Comment: Is it me but when I compile the code you have here it compiles with no error. Assuming I place the code in non-generic class. I'm using C# 3.5 SP1

Comment: My code actually appears in a set of generic extension methods.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem. This code compiles just fine in C# 2, 3 and 4 when you wrap it in a class. If you want an analysis of the problem, please post code that actually demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no difference between `MyAction` and `new Action(MyAction)` (when they're both valid) other than the former won't work in C# 1. This is an `implicit method group conversion`. There are times that this isn't applicable, most notable when the compiler can't work out what kind of delegate you want, e.g.

```
Delegate foo = new Action(MyAction); // Fine
Delegate bar = MyAction; // Nope, can't tell target type
```

This comes into play in your question because both of the methods involved are overloaded. This leads to headaches, basically.

As for the generics side - it's interesting. Method groups don't get much love from C# 3 type inference - I'm not sure whether that's going to be improved in C# 4 or not. If you call a generic method and specify the type argument, type inference works fairly well - but if you try to do it the other way round, it fails:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Valid - it infers Foo<int>
        DoSomething<int>(Foo);
        // Valid - both are specified
        DoSomething<int>(Foo<int>);
        // Invalid - type inference fails
        DoSomething(Foo<int>);
        // Invalid - mismatched types, basically
        DoSomething<int>(Foo<string>);
    }

    static void Foo<T>(T input)
    {
    }

    static void DoSomething<T>(Action<T> action)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Type inference in C# 3 is very complicated, and works well in most cases (in particular it's great for LINQ) but fails in a few others. In an ideal world, it would become easier to understand *and* more powerful in future versions... we'll see!

Comment: Cheers! I accepted the other answer but yours is still helpful too. +1

Answer (score 3):

The non-generic implicit delegate creation is just syntactic sugar, so the compiler generates exactly the same code for

```
DoSomething(MyAction);
```

and

```
DoSomething(new Action(MyAction));
```

as it can infer the type of the delegate directly from the method arguments & context.

With the generic delegate, you have to specify the delegate type due to covariance and contravariance (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174(VS.80).aspx for details) - the T in Action can be a supertype to the T in the method, and it will still be accepted as a delegate method. So, you need to specify the T in the delegate explicitly as the compiler can't figure it out itself.

Comment: Cheers, now I understand. Link to covariance vs contravariance article for those who don't understand: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)

Comment: I'd say it's more to do with the limitations of type inference than co/contravariance, personally. If you read the spec section on type inference (I can't remember it offhand now) you'll see that method groups basically don't get much of a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Just a sidenote.. 
For some reason this works in VB.

Seems the implementation of the preprocessor in C# and VB differ when i comes to converting the  Methodgroup / adderessof to a delegate.