# I can't receive information from a weighing machine connected via serial port in Hyperterminal

Tags: serial-port, hyperterminal

I have an application in Visual Basic which exported as DLL should let Dynamics NAV 2016 get data from a weighting machine. For the connection I use the same data as the old application in an older computer, but I cannot connect even using Hyperterminal:

I have a Windows 98 computer connected to a weighting machine via COM2 serial port and when I try to connect to it using Hyperterminal, it automatically receive the weight in real time.

The issue appears when I try to connect the weighting machine to another computer. I tried to connect to a Windows XP computer using the serial cable and to a Windows 7 computer using an USB adapter. In these cases I cannot receive any data from the weighting machine, and I used the same configuration in the device manager and in the Hyperterminal configuration.

Connection details:

- Port: COM2
- Bits per second: 4800
- Bits per data: 7
- Parity: Space
- Stop bits: 2
- Flow control: None

Do you know any solution to this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SerialPort not receiving any data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907490/serialport-not-receiving-any-data)

Comment: I've read that post, but my problem isn't about programming, it's about hyperterminal not receiving data when the same configuration works on an older computer.