# C# : Serial port not sending data from direct serial port connection, only from Serial to USB converter. (Shekel Merav 2000 Weigh Scale)

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2019; however, this problem seems to occur using various terminal programs.
I am connected to a Shekel Merav 2000 Scale which has a serial connection.

I am using the .Net SerialPort class and using serialPort.DataReceived event.

If I use a USB to serial cable to connect my scale to the PC, everything works fine, the scale continuously streams the weight to me. If I connect the scale directly to the serial port on my PC, the port opens successfully, however nothing is received from the scale.

Is there anything special that the USB converter is doing that "kicks" the serial port into life.

Thanks so much!

I have tried using a program like Serial Port Monitor and it also does not receive data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907490/serialport-not-receiving-any-data

Comment: This is a (poorly described) hardware connection problem, and is off-topic for this site.