# SerialPort Migration from .NET 4.8 to .NET 6 - .NET 8

Tags: c#, async-await, serial-port, .net-6.0, .net-8.0

I want to migrate from .NET 4.8 to .NET 8, in previous version of .NET, we can use serial port by create `SerialPort` object and assign read event to it for get response.

I want to used `ReadAsync` method of `BaseStream` but the method get stuck and ,did not response.

sample :

```
    using System.IO.Ports;
    using System.Text;
    
    while (true)
    { 
        Console.Write("Serial port number : ");
        var port = Console.ReadLine();
        
        Console.Write("Serial baudrate : ");
        var baudrate = Console.ReadLine();
    
        SerialPort serial_port = new SerialPort()
        {
            PortName = $"COM{port}",
            BaudRate = int.Parse(baudrate),
            Parity = Parity.None,
            StopBits = StopBits.One,
            DataBits = 8
        };
    
        try
        {
            serial_port.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to exit (Y/N)?");
            var response = Console.ReadLine();
            if (response.Equals("Y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                return;
            else
                continue;
        }
    
        string response = "";
    
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Send char to Serial : ");
            var command = Console.ReadLine();
            if (command.Equals("exit",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                break;
            
            response = await ReadExists(serial_port.BaseStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
            Console.WriteLine($"Read Exist chars = {response}");
            
            await serial_port.BaseStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command));
            response = await ReadExists(serial_port.BaseStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
            Console.WriteLine($"Read chars exact after write = {response}");
            
            Thread.Sleep(50);
    
            response = await ReadExists(serial_port.BaseStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
            Console.WriteLine($"Read chars exact after write = {response}");
        }
        serial_port.Close();
    }
    
    async Task<string> ReadExists(Stream sr)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        await sr.ReadAsync(buffer).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer.ToArray());
    }
```

code stuck in here :

```
   async Task<string> ReadExists(Stream sr)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
  -->   await sr.ReadAsync(buffer).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer.ToArray());
    }
```

Can anyone suggest best pattern for using serial ports in .NET 8 with async compatibility?

### Answer

I Got the answer :

1. If an empty `Array`  send to `WriteAsync` method ,thread got stuck.
2. For send `Array` to `SerialPort` , first of all we most get count of
   bytes , that we can read with `BytesToRead` method and then call
   `BaseStream.ReadAsync` method.

Correct Code :

```
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text;

while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Serial port number : ");
    var port = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Serial baudrate : ");
    var baudrate = Console.ReadLine();

    SerialPort serial_port = new SerialPort()
    {
        PortName = $"COM{port}",
        BaudRate = int.Parse(baudrate),
        Parity = Parity.None,
        StopBits = StopBits.One,
        DataBits = 8
    };

    try
    {
        serial_port.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to exit (Y/N)?");
        var answer = Console.ReadLine();
        if (answer.Equals("Y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return;
        else
            continue;
    }

    string response = "";

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Send char to Serial : ");
        var command = Console.ReadLine();
        if (command.Equals("exit", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            break;

        response = await ReadExistsStream(serial_port).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine($"Read Exist chars = {response}");

        await serial_port.BaseStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        response = await ReadExistsStream(serial_port).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine($"Read chars exact after write = {response}");

        Thread.Sleep(50);

        response = await ReadExistsStream(serial_port).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine($"Read chars exact after write = {response}");
    }
    serial_port.Close();
}

static async Task<string> ReadExistsStream(SerialPort sp)
{
    int lenght = sp.BytesToRead;
    if (lenght == 0)
        return "";
    byte[] buffer = new byte[lenght];
    await sp.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer.ToArray());
}
```

### Summary

Best way for communicate with `SerialPort` in NET Core Is :

Work with `BaseStream` of `SerialPort` and call `ReadAsync` and `WriteAsync` like above Example.
I made extension for `SerialPort` ,you can see code and used from

[GitHub source code](https://github.com/aghili/Aghili.Extensions.System.IO.Ports)
[NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aghili.Extensions.System.IO.Ports)

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception? What is the OS?

Comment: Please try to present the specific source code and the error situation and message in text. Please refer to this help article. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Or, for example, what would happen if you applied async await to these examples? [Examples - SerialPort Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#examples)

Comment: Or maybe you're using an API that only Windows supports? [SerialDevice Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication.serialdevice?view=winrt-22621)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8910167/17034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

1. If an empty `Array`  send to `WriteAsync` method ,thread got stuck.
2. For send `Array` to `SerialPort` , first of all we most get count of
   bytes , that we can read with `BytesToRead` method and then call
   `BaseStream.ReadAsync` method.

#### Correct Code

```
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text;

while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Serial port number : ");
    var port = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Serial baudrate : ");
    var baudrate = Console.ReadLine();

    SerialPort serial_port = new SerialPort()
    {
        PortName = $"COM{port}",
        BaudRate = int.Parse(baudrate),
        Parity = Parity.None,
        StopBits = StopBits.One,
        DataBits = 8
    };

    try
    {
        serial_port.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to exit (Y/N)?");
        var answer = Console.ReadLine();
        if (answer.Equals("Y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return;
        else
            continue;
    }

    string response = "";

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Send char to Serial : ");
        var command = Console.ReadLine();
        if (command.Equals("exit", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            break;

        response = await ReadExistsStream(serial_port).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine($"Read Exist chars = {response}");

        await serial_port.BaseStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        response = await ReadExistsStream(serial_port).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine($"Read chars exact after write = {response}");

        Thread.Sleep(50);

        response = await ReadExistsStream(serial_port).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine($"Read chars exact after write = {response}");
    }
    serial_port.Close();
}

static async Task<string> ReadExistsStream(SerialPort sp)
{
    int lenght = sp.BytesToRead;
    if (lenght == 0)
        return "";
    byte[] buffer = new byte[lenght];
    await sp.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer.ToArray());
}
```

### Summary

Best way for communicate with `SerialPort` in NET Core Is :

Work with `BaseStream` of `SerialPort` and call `ReadAsync` and `WriteAsync` like above Example.
I made extension for `SerialPort` ,you can see code and used from

[GitHub source code](https://github.com/aghili/Aghili.Extensions.System.IO.Ports)
[NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aghili.Extensions.System.IO.Ports)